# List of double-preposition phrases

Tags: preposition, phrase, phrase-request

I’m looking for a list of ways in which prepositions can be combined with each other to mean new things, for example

> ab und zu – now and then
>
> bis auf – except for

I’ve tried to google this extensively, but Google keeps thinking I’m talking about either two-way prepositions (prepositions that can be either accusative or dative) or verb–preposition combinations.

Comment: Your two examples are different things - I would not see "Ab und zu" as a double preposition - The conjunction between the p.s changes things. "bis" is the most prominent that comes to my mind to form double or even triple prepositions: "Die Strasse reichte **bis hin zu** den Bergen". "Jenseits von" and "diesseits von" are other examples. Some people claim those words are no longer *prepositions* in such a usage, but rather *adverbs*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back when I learned German, I just opened each preposition in [this dictionary](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/auf) and wrote down all combinations. If you check *auf* and *bis*, you will already find:

- auf und ab
- auf und nieder
- bis auf
- bis zu

and a few more. Just go through all of them (they are not that many)!